# Send multiple embeds if there are more than 25 fields (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

I'd like to know how to send multiple embeds if there are more than 25 fields in an embed constructor. I need it to include the remaining fields(where there may be 75 or more at any given time), while retaining the Title, Description, Color, etc.

My Embed is constructed as such, sourcing each .addField() from a for...in loop

```
const shop = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`My Title`)
    .setDescription(`My Description`)
    .setThumbnail('My Thumbnail')
    .setFooter(`My Footer`)

    let listItems = ITEMS;
    for(key in listItems) {
        if (listItems.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            shop.addField(`${listItems[key].name}`, `${commafy(listItems[key].price)}`, true)
        }
    }
message.channel.send(shop);
```

There are more than 25 keys in listItems, and as such, sending the embed vanilla only sends the embed including the first 25 fields.

I know I will need to loop around `shop.fields.length` somewhere, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to get this done.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal in few simple steps!:

- Initialize an array of embeds ( which we will send together after adding fields to them at last )
- Initialize an index variable `i` which would hold how many fields we need.
- Now start by looping through `listItems`,  using a `for...in` loop for value of `listItems` assigning it to a key. we would add them to a singular embed ( 25 per embed ) and then incremenate `i`.
- Further send our array of embeds through the [`TextChannel#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method which accepts [`BaseMessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BaseMessageOptions) which further accepts an `embeds` parameter which accepts a `Type` as an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) objects.

```js
    const all_embeds = [];
    let i = 0;
    for(key in listItems) {
                if (!all_embeds[Math.floor(i / 25)]) { //checks if the embed with the required fields already exists in our array
                    all_embeds.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`My Title`).setDescription(`My Description`).setThumbnail('My Thumbnail').setFooter(`My Footer`)); // add required amount of embeds to our array
                }
                all_embeds[Math.floor(i / 25)].addField(`${listItems[key].name}`, `${(listItems[key].price)}`, true);
                i++;
            }
            message.channel.send({
                embeds: [all_embeds]
            });
```

Comment: Struggling to adapt your code to my scenario. i cannot use forEach as i am not looping through an array, im looping through properties of an object. I believe I need to adapt this with a for...in loop to do so.

Comment: You may do so with a `for...in` loop too! Just follow your own setup! It'd be exactly the same, the index variable gets incremented even in a for...in loop :) if you have further doubts as so how something would happen feel free to drop another comment

Comment: I'm getting the following error, `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message` => I changed `.send({embeds: [all_embeds]});` to `.send({embed: [all_embeds]});` (im on v12 i think i have to do that) and then I get the following error with that `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: This field is required,
embeds[0].description: This field is required`

Comment: your edit is exactly what i had tried changing my code to, see above comment , changed `embeds` to `embed` and then receive the invalid form body errors. Do you have discord? We could move to DMs if thatd be easier to come up with a solution? (lol i just asked if you have discord when were coding in discord.js)

Comment: You don't have to change embeds to embed, it would remain embeds, please read the attached documentation, also yes my discord is 0_0#6666 you may contact me by joining my server [here](https://discord.gg/ZeroSync)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236883/discussion-between-ex-c0n-and-zero).